# What's the difference between polylogarithmic and logarithmic?

Tags: complexity

I can't imagine one that is not *polylogarithmic*
but *logarithmic*.

$O(\log N)$ satisfies both.

What about $O(\log^{3}N)$, $O(\log^{100}N)$, and  $O(\log^{10000}N)$ ?

Let's say $N=10^{10}$

Comment: What's the context of this? I'm not sure this difference matters a lot in cryptography.

Comment: I saw one paper a few years ago with Goldwasser that had a polylog function, so understanding the definition would make sense. But it would be nice if OP gave some crypto context, yes.

Comment: [Here's what I was remembering](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2450227)

Comment: What is _one_ in your question? A problem? Also, if you fix $N=10^{10}$ they are all O(1) :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about cryptography as defined in our help center.

Comment: I should have mentioned the utility of this topic. Since papers from crypto community explicitly use the terms $\mathsf{polylogarithmic}$ and $\mathsf{logarithmic}$, not interchangeably.

Comment: Yes, log N satisfies that and there is nothing strange here. All logarithmic functions are also polylogarithmic just like all linear functions are also polynomials.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Definitions:

An algorithm is said to run in

- logarithmic time if $T(n) = O(log(n))$
- polylogarithmic time if $T(n) = O(log(n)^k)$ (also written as $T(n) = O(log^k(n))$)

That means they are the same for $k=1$. Otherwise they are different and your other examples are all polylogarithmic.
I'm not sure how exactly to explain *what* the difference is but maybe a picture will help you:

[image: log(x) and log^3(x)]

Comment: What does ^() approach as n goes to infinity? Does it approach a line n?

Comment: Some quick plotting in python shows that it seems to grow very fast initially, but at some point, will still grow slower than n. Basically approaches:
___
|
as opposed to
  /
 /
If this is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: Ah comments don't show newlines, so my simple ascii plot didn't format. Basically a corner that goes vertically up then horizontal (when very zoomed out compared to the diagonal line n)

Answer (score 7):

An algorithm is said to take logarithmic time if `T(n) = O(log n)`.

An algorithm is said to run in polylogarithmic time if `T(n) = O((log n)^k)`, for some constant k.

> [**Wikipedia: Time complexity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Logarithmic_time)
>
> **Logarithmic time**
>
> An algorithm is said to take logarithmic time if $T(n) = O(\log n)$.  Due
>   to the use of the binary numeral system by computers, the logarithm is
>   frequently base 2 (that is, $\log_2 n$, sometimes written $\lg n$).  However,
>   by the change of base for logarithms, $\log_a n$ and $\log_b n$ differ only by
>   a constant multiplier, which in big-$O$ notation is discarded; thus
>   $O(\log n)$ is the standard notation for logarithmic time algorithms
>   regardless of the base of the logarithm.
>
> Algorithms taking logarithmic time are commonly found in operations on
>   binary trees or when using binary search.
>
> An $O(\log n)$ algorithm is considered highly efficient, as the
>   operations per instance required to complete decrease with each
>   instance.
>
> A very simple example of this type is an algorithm that cuts a string
>   in half, then cuts the right half in half, and so on. It will take
>   $O(\log n)$ time ($n$ being the length of the string) since we chop the
>   string in half before each print (we make the assumption that
>   console.log and str.substring run in constant time). This means, in
>   order to increase the number of prints, we have to double the length
>   of the string.
>
> **Polylogarithmic time**
>
> An algorithm is said to run in polylogarithmic time if $T(n) = O((\log n)^k)$, for some constant $k$. For example, matrix chain ordering can be
>   solved in polylogarithmic time on a Parallel Random Access Machine.

Comment: thanks for your quick response! Is there any borderline b/w them?

Comment: @zorutic - for O((log n)^k), when k=1 than it is Logarithmic time

Comment: Your polylogarithmic time expression is missing a `^`. ​ ​